# Ошибка gulp при сборке js файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

При запуске сборки в отдается ошибка:

The following tasks did not complete: default
Did you forget to signal async completion?

При этом файл успешно создается и код внутри присутствует. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем причина

```js
{
  "name": "gulp-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.babel.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.5.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0-beta.2"
  }
}
```

```js
import { src, pipe, dest } from 'gulp';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import babelify from 'babelify';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';

function processJs() {
    browserify({
        entries: ['./src/js/index.js', './src/js/index2.js']
    })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
        presets: ["@babel/env"]
    }))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('result.js'))
    .pipe(dest('./dest/js'))
}


export default processJs;
```

Comment: gulp'у требуется знать, когда код внутри обработчика выполнится, по этому надо либо использовать async, либо вызывать коллбек, который приходит первым аргументом в функцию. Это желаемое поведение, по этому код все же выполняется, но предупреждение выводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недоставало **return** в начале потока, с ним ошибок нет